# Windows Server 2008 R2 Kernelbase.dll exceptions

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, kernel

Hi we have a Windows Server 2008 R2 server that has been having issues lately.  Right at the same time as most of the issues started happening I noticed that there are lots of exceptions in the logs for KERNELBASE.dll - This doesn't look good, I'm wondering if anyone out there can help me interpret this event from the event log? Thanks.

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17651, time stamp: 0x4e21213c
Exception code: 0xe053534f
Fault offset: 0x000000000000cacd
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
Report Id: %13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line gives you much more detail:

Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2

w3wp.exe is the IIS .NET Worker Process.  You obviously have some sort of ASP.NET application running on the server.  More important this points to a problem with the application you are running, most likely a code error causing the entire site to crash and the worker process to recycle.

KernelBase errors are fairly generic, but at this point I would start looking to your application, your devs/vendor and going from there.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that part earlier but started focusing on KERNELBASE ;)  This is part of a larger issue and I think these errors are a byproduct of the larger networking issue. E.g. the w3p process is trying to load an external page and it can't.  Out of curiosity though do you know of a way to identify which app pool / site this is coming from? The application path is %11 which doesn't seem to mean anything since the other variables increment, e.g. %12 %13 it doesn't look like these contain meaningful information.

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head.  It looks like variables that the logger was not able to populate.

Comment: This article shows you (with pictures!) how to trigger a dump when that 0xe053534f (stack overflow) exception occurs, which will you give you much greater insight into the error: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/03/20/debugging-a-net-crash-with-rules-in-debug-diag.aspx

Comment: Got same error in our new servers few weeks ago, post and commends help us a lot. Thanks